# SBT error: java.lang.RuntimeException: No main class detected

Tags: scala, build, sbt

Update:
I need put libraryDependencies for using Actor in Scala.

```
libraryDependencies <++= scalaVersion(v =>
  Seq("org.scala-lang" % "scala-actors" % v)
)
```

---

when I ran "sbt run", I could successfully pass the compilation but then failed on run the code.

Here is the error:
 java.lang.RuntimeException: No main class detected.

The weird thing is when I do not use SBT, I can run it without any issue:

```
>scalac actor.scala
>scala pingpong
```

Any idea why this happens?

I am using SBT 0.13.0
Scala version is 2.10.2

Thanks

### Deryk.

Here is my code:

```
import scala.actors.Actor
import scala.actors.Actor._

case object Ping;
case object Pong;
case object Stop;

class Ping(count:Int, pong:Actor) extends Actor
{
    def act()
    {
        var counter = count -1 ;
        pong ! Ping;
        loop
        {
            react
            {
                case Pong =>
                if( (counter < count) && (counter > 0) ) {Console.println(counter+"->Ping: pong"); pong ! Ping; counter = counter -1;} 
                else {pong ! Stop;exit()}

            }
        }
    }
}

class Pong extends Actor
{
    def act()
    {
        loop
        {
            react
            {
               case Ping => {Console.println("Pong: Ping"); sender ! Pong;}
               case Stop => {Console.println("Ping Pong Communication is done!");exit()}
            }
        }
    }
}

object pingpong
{
    def main(args: Array[String])
    {
        println(util.Properties.versionString)
        val pong = new Pong

        val ping = new Ping(5, pong)

        ping.start
        pong.start
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use Actor in Scala, you need include the library, as the following:

```
libraryDependencies <++= scalaVersion(v =>
  Seq("org.scala-lang" % "scala-actors" % v)
)
```

Answer (score 5):

Try this in your build file:

```
mainClass in (Compile,run) := Some("pingpong")
```

Comment: Still no luck:
 (run-main) java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: pingpong
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: pingpong
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.findClass(ClassLoader.java:382)
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:323)

here is my build.sbt:

name := "test"

version := "1.0"

mainClass := Some("pingpong")

Comment: Yes, I only have one file "actor.scala" under src/main/scala

Comment: Try `object pingpong extends App` and remove the main declaration.

Comment: Your `mainClass` definition doesn't match what I said before. As I said, try `mainClass in (Compile,run) := Some("pingpong")`. Not just `mainClass := Some("pingpong")`.

Comment: Glad to hear it. If it was my answer and comments that helped, please accept my answer. If it was your own magic, please add it as an answer and accept your own solution to help others down the road.

Comment: I will put it as answered later on (8 hours later). It is not related to mainClass. It is actually library dependency issue, as I show in "Update".

Comment: Interesting. Nice job.

Answer (score 4):

I have this exception if I try to use class instead of object.

```
//class Foo extends App {
//    print("No main class detected")
//}

object Foo extends App {
    print("Hello World")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's looking for an object.  Try creating a simple clock.scala object file and re-running it:

```
object Clock {
  def main(args: Array[String]) = println(new java.util.Date)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to move your class which extends App to *src/main/scala* folder. Otherwise you have to create *main* method